# ArrayList and List<object> - Not List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, arraylist

My last interview went like this!

EDIT:

The linked question seems to be answering the question but its not. I have already in the below code-snippet mentioned that. The question is other than that, whats the difference?.

What is the difference between `ArrayList` and `List<object>` ?

(They were asking specifically about `List<object>` not `List<T>`)!

1. My explanation is we cannot use `ForEach` extension method for `ArrayList` and `ArrayList` is a non-generic functionality.

   ```
       ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
       List<object> listObjects = new List<object>();

       foreach(object item in arrayList)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(item);
       }

       listObjects.ForEach(item => {
           Console.WriteLine(item);
       });
   ```

I explained this to my interviewer but she seemed to be expecting something else. Anything  other than that?

Comment: ArrayList?? what? no one uses that dude, this is not java for God's sake.

Comment: @HighCore: Well, I second you. But these `damn interviewers` still seemed concerned with it! :(

Comment: She was probably after the boxing/unboxing of structs. eg/ ArrayList of ints versus `List<int>`

Comment: @Jamiec: could you please explain that?

Comment: It's hard to read the mind of your interviewer to see what exactly she was expecting to hear. The best person to ask about it would be her.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. the problem is that many people believe it's 1990, or that C# is java, when clearly it is not.

Comment: @Jamiec: Fine, I asked her if she really meant `List<objects>` and she responded `yes`. Really hard `how to answer these type of questions` even when you went `well prepared.`

Comment: ForEach is a normal method of List<T>, not an extension method. If it were, it would probably be usable on ArrayList, too.

Comment: I actually disagree with the close *reason* but not the close. We're not going to be able to give you a satisfactory answer - only the interviewer is.

Comment: IIRC, `List<T>` were introduced at the same time when generics were. So it's the replacement for `ArrayList`, which is pretty the same in case of `List<object>`, but `LINQ` can be used over `IEnumerable<T>` not `IEnumerable`. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` while `ArrayList` certainly not.

Comment: @Jamiec: Well. Yes. :)